# ACT urls have lots of backslashes - "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters."

Tags: url, act, shortlist

My logout and other ACT urls all seem to have a lot of backslashes in the URL

I'm using the module shortlist and when clicking add it takes you to:

http://eogee.rmdyapps.co.uk/////////?ACT=39&p=YToyOntzOjg6ImVudHJ5X2lkIjtzOjM6IjgzNiI7czoxMToiY2xvbmVkX2Zyb20iO2I6MDt9&ret=http%3A%2F%2Feogee.rmdyapps.co.uk%2Fwhat-we-do%2Fsustainability%2Fsigns-tool%2Fafirm-apparel-and-footwear-international-rsl-management

This then shows the error "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters."

My logout URL is also showing as:

http://eogee.rmdyapps.co.uk/////////?ACT=16&csrf_token=e836df2db8ce7415437de6a9ddb938e613d12aa8

Any idea as to why it's adding in these additional backslashes? seems to be causing all sorts of issues.

Thanks!

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue... I am still looking for a solution to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was due to the transcribe module doing strange things, once disabled everything worked as expected